# What is the likelihood that they will see all the 5 posters? in 5 different elevators?

Tags: probability

We are putting up 5 different posters in 5 different elevators for 5 days. There are 300 staff accessing the elevators. The elevators cover 6 floors. Staff normally go up to their office 4 times a day and down 4 times a day (arriving in the morning, coffee break, lunch, afternoon break, and then going home).  What is the likelihood that they will see all the 5 posters?

The context is that there was a debate with colleagues on that maybe it was not a smart choice to have 5 different posters but stick to one generic poster to raise awareness of a presentation session. My argument for different posters was that people in our office rarely respond to the "vision" of the organization messages but rather respond better to something that they have issues with in their particular area frequently. Thus, a more probing message on the posters that will be put in 5 elevators that trigger interest.

Their argument for a generic poster was that people following patterns would take the same elevator all the time and thus miss the different posters. The staff can, of course, not choose which elevator would come to their floor when they press the button thus in my view they would have to then ignore elevators arriving at their floor, which would be unlikely.

What we would like to achieve is simply that the 300 staff at one or more times have seen all posters during the week that they are exposed so that potentially the one related to their area of expertise would generate interest to come to the session.

Sorry if I am not clear enough on the question. I am not good at math in general but the questioning triggered my interest as to understand how you actually would calculate such.

Any help to further my understanding would be most appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your own thoughts on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I ran a simple simulation, assuming a uniform random choice of elevator each time a staff member uses an elevator. Given that a staff member uses an elevator 8 times a day on each of 5 days, that staff member has greater than 99.93% chance of entering each elevator at least once, and therefore seeing each poster at least once. With 300 staff members, this gives a greater than 81% chance that all staff members will see each poster at least once.

Comment: @Logophobic  Thank you very much. Very interesting result. It clearly convinces me we are on the right track having different messages in the elevators.

Comment: One thing to note: the actual choice of elevator is certainly not uniformly random. There may be a number of variables that affect choice of elevator which I would not be able to account for. I would assume constant unequal probabilities for each elevator and rotate the posters so that each poster appears in each elevator for one full day to offset any bias.

Comment: @Logophobic i agree that the choice of elevator is not uniform. What I understand there are special algorithms for elevators when they are clustered thus some might be prioritzed different ways at different times. So yes it might be better to shift the posters around each day as you mention.